# <function trip_cost at 0x7f8772ac6848>

Tags: python

```
def hotel_cost(nights):    
    return 140*nights
def  plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city=="Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city=="Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city=="Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city=="Los Angeles":
        return 475
def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost=days*40
    if days>=7:
        cost=cost-50
    elif days>=3:
        cost=cost-20
    return cost 
def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money    
trip_cost("Los Angeles",5,600)
print  trip_cost
```

Why is it showing in the console panel as

```
<function trip_cost at 0x7f8772ac6848>
```

Comment: thanks @Work of Artiz

Answer (score 2):

So trip_cost is a function.

```
print trip_cost
```

therefore just prints the pointer to the function.

I think you mean to do something like:

```
res = trip_cost("Los Angeles",5,600)
print res
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing function reference, just use:

```
print( trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600) )
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the datetime library date is a keyword 
Use `print '%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s' % ( now.month, now.day, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)`
instead of `print '%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s' % ( now.month, now.date, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)`.